# Sum column of a hierarchical index?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, indexing

The DataFrame without sum for column of a hierarchical index:

```
  dex1 dex2 dex3 one  two 
    H   D   A    1    2     
            B    4    5     
            C    7    8    
    I   E   A    1    1     
            B    2    2      
            C    3    3
```

The DataFrame with sum for a column of a hierarchical index should be, for columns df['one'] index dex1, 12 (1 + 4 + 7), 6 (1 + 2 + 3) and for column df['two'] of index dex1, 12 (1 + 4 + 7), 6 (1 + 2 + 3).

So far, I have tried:

```
df.loc[dex1].sum['one']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(level='dex1').sum()
print (df1)
      one  two
dex1          
H      12   15
I       6    6
```

From version of pandas `0.20.0` is possible [omit `level`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements) parameter.

```
df1 = df.groupby('dex1').sum()
print (df1)
      one  two
dex1          
H      12   15
I       6    6
```

---

Or use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with parameter `level`:

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0)
print (df1)
      one  two
dex1          
H      12   15
I       6    6
```

```
df1 = df.sum(level='dex1')
print (df1)
      one  two
dex1          
H      12   15
I       6    6
```

Comment: This answer is correct as implemented. For my purposes, I try to avoid using .groupby(), so df.sum(level=int) works great. Thank you!

Comment: For clarification, when you say it is possible in pandas 0.20.1 to omit level, that one can say df1 = df.groupby('dex1').sum()?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I add link.